# Error referring to Meteor object in settings.json

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor server code is printing this error to the console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'BT_PRIVATE_KEY' of undefined

```js
'braintreeConn': () => {
      let env;
      // Pick Braintree environment based on environment defined in Meteor settings.
      if (Meteor.settings.public.env === 'Production') {
        env = Braintree.Environment.Production;
      } else {
        env = Braintree.Environment.Sandbox;
      }
      // Initialize Braintree connection:
      gateway = BrainTreeConnect({
        environment: env,
        publicKey: Meteor.settings.public.BT_PUBLIC_KEY,
        privateKey: Meteor.settings.private.BT_PRIVATE_KEY, //<--------Error----
        merchantId: Meteor.settings.public.BT_MERCHANT_ID
      });
    }
```

Here is the settings.json

```js
{
  "env": {
    "MONGO_URL":"mongodb://someURL"
  },
  "public" : {
    "env": "Sandbox",
    "BT_MERCHANT_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "BT_PUBLIC_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "private": {
    "BT_PRIVATE_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Any idea why? and how to fix it? thx

**edit**
I am running meteor like this:

`MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor meteor --port=4000`

Comment: its just saying one or more parent keys are missing ... confirm you have a valid  Meteor.settings.private

Comment: how are you running meteor? `meteor --settings settings.json` doing this?

Comment: No. Please see the answer in **edit**, but if this is the issue, can I remove it from settings into a file scope object and run it just using `meteor`?

Answer (score 0):

Settings in the private section of the settings.json are only readable on the server.  Be sure this code is not being executed in  shared / client space because that would generate this EXACT error.